# Sign up and Login logic regarding firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, firebase-authentication

Is the Signup and Login logic for firebase same if im using google authentication. I want to make page for user authentication but i dont know should I make two pages one for signup and one for login, its because only one button is used to authenticate user through google authentication

Comment: Maybe less is more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [sign in to Firebase with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin), it is a two-step process:

1. First you sign in to Google, where you provide your credentials (such as email+password).
2. Then your app uses the credentials from Google to sign the user in to Firebase.

You'll note that there is no step where the user signs **up** with Firebase here, as they already signed up (and signed in) with Google by the time you call Firebase. So it is not required to have a sign-up page in your app in this scenario.

It *may* still be useful to have a registration page, where you send the people who sign-in to your app for the first time. In such a page you can ask them for details you don't/can't get from Google Authentication, allow the to change details that you *can* get from Google (such as the display name they want to use in your app), and then store those in your own database.

Comment: Alright Thanks, I'll keep that in mind